# Making strong Login / Register Login system with classes

Tags: python

I'm trying to do a strong login / register system with PostgreSQL. And one thing that doesn't let me do the job is thinking about client-side application working principle.

Imagine this app is running by 1000 people and how do I have to define the variables? Recently I was talking with my friend programmer, he said that I should use some sort of `self.email`, `self.password` variables in classes. But I didn't understand this. Besides I can do register, login system easily without any classes and `self` references, I would just used the global variables, but my friend said that with each new user the global variables overwrite.

So what's the best way to create login/register system without overwriting anyone's user?

Here's my code which I tried to do with classes.

This is Client-Side application.

`Main.py`:

```
from Account import Register

class Main():
    def __init__(self):
        self.isregistered = input('Registered or no? (Y/N) : ')
        if self.isregistered == 'Y':
            print('logg in...')
            pass
        else:
            self.register_name = Register()
            print(self.register_name)

    def return_register_name(self):
        print(self.register_name)

Main()
```

This is the `Account.py` module which includes `Register()`:

```
import getpass

def Register():
    a = input('enter your name ')
    b = getpass.getpass('enter your psw ')
    return a, b

def Login():
    login_user = input('Login name ')
    login_psw = getpass.getpass('Login pass ')
```

Comment: Look at django source code, or flask-XXX both of them have login/register system implemented, this will give you all the informations you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can think to use cookies or session with django:

Session: https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Sessions

Cookie: https://www.tangowithdjango.com/book/chapters/cookie.html

Session i think it's what you want, beacause cookie can be store for long time, you need to create a new session with user's data when user login, and destroy when logout. Session and coockie are differently for each user, so nothing is overwritten

Comment: I don't need to store my passwords, I also will not use Django as a webserver, I would use flask or aiohttp.

Comment: Your problem is if many people try to login in same time which is the value of variables?

Comment: Maybe that's it, that's what I'm asking, should I use these classes somehow or what should I use. For now I'm working on a CMD and for DB I use PostgreSQL. I would like to start aiohttp or flask with vue.js

Comment: If many people doing same action in same time there will be for each one a differente request, so there will not be overwriting of variables

Comment: That's what I was asking for:)